# No MySQL records return when past a certain limit?

Tags: mysql, sql-limit

I have the following query which returns 250 records:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM Persons AS p
                      INNER JOIN Colors AS c ON c.ColorId = p.FavoriteColorId 
WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe' AND c.ColorName IN ('RED','BLUE','YELLOW')
                      LIMIT 240,10;

-- Returns 198 records
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM Persons AS p
                      INNER JOIN Colors AS c ON c.ColorId = p.FavoriteColorId 
WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe' AND c.ColorName IN ('RED','BLUE','YELLOW')

-- Returns 250 records. Why?
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM Persons AS p
                      INNER JOIN Colors AS c ON c.ColorId = p.FavoriteColorId 
WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe' AND c.ColorName IN ('RED','BLUE','YELLOW')
```

When I execute the above, I see no records even though there are 250 total.  It only starts to return records when I change the `LIMIT` to `LIMIT 197,10`, then I see 1 of the records.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you get 250 rows if you remove the `LIMIT` altogether?

Comment: @Travesty3 - Yes, I get all 250 rows.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Are you sure for `c.FavoriteColorId` in the `WHERE` since there is `p.FavoriteColorId` in the `ON` clause?

Comment: @FabienTheSolution - Fixed, made a mistake, it is c.ColorName.

Comment: Try this `SELECT DISTINCT p.*, c.ColorName ...` ? Do you get the last 10 rows now?

Comment: I just executed the same exact query again and I am curious is there some internal ordering going on here.  I had previously executed it like 50 times with no results and now it is returning 10 records with no changes.

Comment: My guess is you have 198 records that meet your criteria.  Thus when you reduce the offset amount to `197` you see your first record and you only see one record because it is the only one the falls within the range requested.

Comment: @Xaisoft In most cases, you will need to specify and ordering on a query using `LIMIT` if you want to get get consistent results.

Comment: Ok, I figured out why I started getting records and I lied, I did slightly modify the query.  When I have `SELECT DISTINCT p.*...` with the large offset, I get nothing, but when I have `SELECT DISTINCT p.*, c.ColorName`, I get records.  The problem here is that I don't want to return c.ColorName.

Comment: @MikeBrant - Do you think my count is off? I just did a distinct count and it is 250.  How do I know what to order by though? Especially if I have many columns. One of my tables has 100+ columns.

Comment: @Xaisoft I think that if you are running the same query on a static set of data and only varying the LIMIT parameters, that based on your comment that you tried to do `LIMIT 240,10` and had to lower your offset to `197` before you returned a record, that this would indicate you have 198 records that meet the filtering criteria.

Comment: @MikeBrant - so there could potentially be something wrong with my query that is returning an incorrect count?

Comment: I double checked the count and it is correct, there are 250 records total.  Is it because I am not including anything from the inner join in the select clause?

Comment: @Xaisoft There are 250 records in total where? On the Persons table? On the Colors table? When you run the query with no `LIMIT`?

Comment: When I run the query as I posted with the inner join, but I did individual colors and then added them up and it totaled 250 records.

Comment: @MikeBrant - When I include certain columns from the inner table, I get the records, I have no idea why?

Comment: @Xaisoft That might not be the same query if you did colors individually.  What happens when you run the SAME EXACT QUERY as in your question only without the LIMIT?

Comment: @MikeBrant - OK, I discovered a couple things. If I run the same query wthout limit, I get 198 total records.  If I remove the DISTINCT, I get 250 records.  I need was using DISTINCT because I am showing this in a header/detail table and I want to avoid showing duplicate header records.

Comment: I can see in the data that there are definitely duplicates without the distinct, the problem is how can I get the correct count when using the inner join.  When I do a SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) with the same query, it says 249, so why when I execute it using SELECT DISTINCT p.*, do I see 198

Comment: @MikeBrant - I updated my post with the queries I am running.

Comment: @MikeBrant - I noticed running SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS returns the correct result, for example: `SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS...`, but I noticed this is horribly slow on tables with lots of data

Comment: @Xaisoft So there ARE 198 records meeting that criteria. Your other query doesn't even make sense to me. can you explain in words where you are trying to do, as selecting distinct count values doesn't seem to be doing anything useful.

Comment: @MikeBrant - I am selected from persons where the name is 'Joe Smith` and the color name is red,blue,yellow.  Why do I get 198 records when I do a SELECT DISTINCT *, but when I do a COUNT(*), it returns 250?

Comment: @Xaisoft You are selecting DISTINCT COUNT values which has no meaning. Not to mention you are selecting across `*` in the second query and not `p.*`. You still haven't really explained what the outcome you are looking for is. Like "I want to get distinct records from table P where the person's name is X and their favorite color is either A, B, or C?  Is that what you are after? Or do you simply want a count of such records (i.e. one record in the result set with the count value)?

Comment: @MikeBrant - I want exactly what you said, but both, I want the result and the count.

Comment: @echo_Me - I tried both way and it says i have an eror near *)

Comment: @echo_Me - If I do SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.Id), it works and brings back the correct results.  Thanks, that is a good step.  The one problem I see is that not all my tables have unique columns, some are a combination, so hopefully I can put multiple columns in the with the DISTINCT.

Comment: can you show some sample data or a fiddle so we can see ?

Comment: yes you should use distinct inside the count

Comment: @Xaisoft So perhaps you need to do `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.*) FROM ...` which would only return 1 row with the count.

Comment: @MikeBrant i already told him this

Comment: @echo_Me Yes I saw that conversation pop up while typing my comment :)

Comment: @Xaisoft will my edited answer help now ?

Comment: @MikeBrant - I tried it with p.* and it says it is a syntax error, but if I specify and individual column, it works and I guess for tables that have a composite unique column, I have to just include those.  I don't believe you can do COUNT(DISTINCT p.*), at least not in my case as it is giving me an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have distinct in the wrong place for the count. Your counting all rows (250) and selecting the distinct row values. There is only 1 row which is 250.

What you meant was select count(distinct p.*) Which will then return 198

Answer (score 0):

By default the order is `ASC`

try to reverse the order and get only 10 records like that

```
     Order by RAND ()  LIMIT 10
```

[Without ORDER BY, there is no default sort order.](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx)
so if you are not specified the order then its random then you can simply limit 10 records without setting the position 240.

EDIT:

```
 SELECT  COUNT(*) as counts FROM Persons AS p
                  INNER JOIN Colors AS c ON c.ColorId = p.FavoriteColorId 
 WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe' AND c.ColorName IN ('RED','BLUE','YELLOW')
 GROUP BY c.Id ORDER BY c.Id LIMIT 240,10
```

Comment: Order what though, just some random column?

Comment: @Xaisoft you said its fixed ?

Comment: no, I mean the IN clause is fixed, I had `c.FavoriteColorId IN...`, I mean to put `c.ColorName IN...`  However, when I ran it again in the query browser with LIMI 240,10, it returned records this time and I did not change a thing.  Is there some internal ordering going on here?

Comment: I need to use the offset part because I am using this in paging.

Answer (score 0):

I've re-read the question, and it's not clear to me which queries are returning what.

What we'd expect:

- first query: no rows returned (only 198 distinct rows, there aren't 240 rows to skip)
- second query: 198 rows returned, sounds reasonable
- third query: returns 1 row with value of 250, which again is reasonable.

If that's the behavior you are seeing, then this is all to be expected.

The DISTINCT operator eliminates duplicate rows, which explains the difference between 198 and 250. And since the LIMIT is applied as the last step (or nearly the last step) in the execution plan, that explains why no rows are returned by the first query.

To get the count of the 198 rows returned by the second query, one easy way to get that would be to wrap that second query (which returns the 198 rows) in another query that gets a COUNT from that.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS mycount
  FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT p.*
           FROM Persons p
           JOIN Colors c
             ON c.ColorId = p.FavoriteColorId
            AND c.ColorName IN ('RED','BLUE','YELLOW')
          WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe'
       ) q
```

If you want a count of rows from the `Persons` table, without eliminating any duplicates from the Persons table, then one way to get that would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS mycount
  FROM Persons p
 WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe'
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                  FROM Colors c
                 WHERE c.ColorName IN ('RED','BLUE','YELLOW')
                   AND c.ColorId = p.FavoriteColorId
              )
```

If you have a single column that is UNIQUE and NOT NULL in the Persons table, for example, an `id INT PRIMARY KEY`, you could do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS mycount
  FROM Persons p
  JOIN Colors c 
    ON c.ColorName IN ('RED','BLUE','YELLOW')
   AND c.ColorId = p.FavoriteColorId
 WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe'
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

That first query should be returning no more than 10 rows.

You report that the second query returns 198 rows. I don't see how that first query (identical to this except for the addition the LIMIT clause) should be returning any rows, if that's true.

The third query should be returning a single row.

There's no good explanation for the results you are seeing.

> **Q** Can you replicate this behavior in the msyql command line client, just to rule out behavior in the client application you are using.
>
> **Q** What version of MySQL are you running? (This could be a bug in your version of MySQL.)
>
> **Q** What engine are these tables using (MyISAM, InnoDB)?
>
> **Q** Have you verified your tables are consistent with `CHECK TABLE tablename EXTENDED`?
>
> **Q** And you've verified that some other process isn't inserting, updating and/or deleting rows while your queries are running?

Your first query is a bit odd, in that it specifies a `LIMIT` clause, but there is no `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` clause or anything else that prescribes what order the rows should be returned in.

The third query is a bit odd in that the `DISTINCT` keyword is not needed. Absent a `GROUP BY` clause, we expect `SELECT COUNT(*)` to return a single row.

Part of me questions whether the reporting of the observed behavior is accurate. Is that third query really returning 250 rows, or is it returning a single row with a value of 250 for the count? (Those are two very different things.)

We'd normally expect a `SELECT COUNT(*)` to return a value *larger* than the the number of rows returned by `SELECT DISTINCT p.*` in cases where the `DISTINCT` operator is eliminating duplicate rows.

Comment: just little disign if you dare :)