# What is the reason the counts are different in the mysql queries?

Tags: mysql, count, mysql-5.5

When I run the following queries with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` or specify all the colors `RED,BLUE,YELLOW` in the sub-query using an `IN` clause, I get a record count of `198`.  But when I do each color individually, I get a `COUNT` that adds up to `248 (72 + 59 + 118)`.  Where are the extra 50 rows coming from?  I would have thought that if I did them individually and then added them up, I would get `198`, but I am getting `248`.  Am I viewing how the IN clause works incorrectly?  I would prefer to use `COUNT` instead of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` because I have found `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to be much slower (+3 seconds)

Here are few stats:

```
1. I am running MySQL Version: 5.5.2 
2. The tables engine is INNODB.
3. All the `CHECK TABLE .... EXTENDED` return OK.

-- Returns 198
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT p.* FROM Persons AS p
INNER JOIN Colors AS c ON c.PersonId = p.Id
WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe' AND c.ColorName IN ('YELLOW','RED','BLUE');
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

-- Returns 198
SELECT COUNT(1) as MyCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM Persons AS p
INNER JOIN Colors AS c ON c.PersonId = p.Id
WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe' AND c.ColorName IN ('YELLOW','RED','BLUE')) all;

-- Returns 72
SELECT COUNT(1) as MyCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM Persons AS p
INNER JOIN Colors AS c ON c.PersonId = p.Id
WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe' AND c.ColorName IN ('RED')) red;

-- Returns 59
SELECT COUNT(1) as MyCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM Persons AS p
INNER JOIN Colors AS c ON c.PersonId = p.Id
WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe' AND c.ColorName IN ('BLUE')) blue;

-- Returns 118
SELECT COUNT(1) as MyCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM Persons AS p
INNER JOIN Colors AS c ON c.PersonId = p.Id
WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe' AND c.ColorName IN ('YELLOW')) yellow;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025315/no-mysql-records-return-when-past-a-certain-limit

Comment: @MitchWheat - Yeah, it was put on hold and this makes more sense and is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is happening:

`Persons` table

```
ID  Name
--  ------------
 1  John Doe
 2  Xaisoft
```

`Colors` table

```
PersonID  ColorName
--------  ---------
       1  Red
       1  Yellow
       2  Yellow
```

Now query `Persons.*` for `John Doe` while joining to `Colors`:

```
 SELECT p.*
 FROM Persons p
 INNER JOIN Colors C ON c.PersonID = p.ID
 WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe';
```

Your result will be one `p.*` row *for each color under John Doe*:

```
ID  Name
--  ------------
 1  John Doe
 1  John Doe
```

If you apply a `COUNT DISTINCT` against this you'll end up with `1`.

If you count `Red` and `Yellow` separately, you'll get one for each query. Add them up and you'll get `2`.

---

Look at it this way: if you throw out the `COUNT` and just `SELECT DISTINCT Persons.*` you get these results:

*Red or Yellow for John Doe*:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p.*
 FROM Persons p
 INNER JOIN Colors C ON c.PersonID = p.ID
 WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe'
   AND c.ColorName IN ('RED', 'YELLOW');

ID  Name
--  ----------
 1  John Doe
```

*Red only for John Doe*:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p.*
 FROM Persons p
 INNER JOIN Colors C ON c.PersonID = p.ID
 WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe'
   AND c.ColorName IN ('RED');

ID  Name
--  ----------
 1  John Doe
```

*Yellow only for John Doe*:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p.*
 FROM Persons p
 INNER JOIN Colors C ON c.PersonID = p.ID
 WHERE p.Name = 'John Doe'
   AND c.ColorName IN ('YELLOW');

ID  Name
--  ----------
 1  John Doe
```

Comment: But I am applying a DISTINCT COUNT to the individual ones.

Comment: But your distinct count is based on the `Persons` table only, not on the person and the colors. I've added an example to my answer; take a look. If that doesn't make sense, please try running your second through fifth queries above starting with `SELECT * FROM` instead of `SELECT COUNT(1) as MyCount FROM`. You'll get repeat names across queries 3, 4, and 5. These names are *not* repeated for query 2 because of the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I modified my query here to see what was actually being returned from the inner table and I did notice repetition or non-distinct values which would explain the extra rows.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. To be honest, I still don't quite understand it 100%, but I am half way there :)